# Can nesting of group functions be done in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query in mysql:

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(Population)) FROM country GROUP BY region;
```

But I am getting the error below:

```
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function 0.000 sec
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: it's chicken/egg. avg()'s results won't be ready until all the rows/groups have been processed, while max() internally processes row-by-row and keeps track of what the largest value found so far is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple aggregation functions at once. But you can use instead

```
select avg(Population) as avg_population
from country
group by region
order by avg_population desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Or use a subquery, but I suppose this approach is more performant.